Expo (EAS) Run 1st build non-interactively
I have configured GitLab CI to automate the build + submission for iOS. Which is working fine. But it requires to run the 1st build+submission interactively. Can we eliminate this requirement?
Actually we are working on a tool which generates code for different applications. After that a I need to interactively configure, build and submit that app to Apple Testflight for the 1st time. This needs to be done for each and every application generated.
The next builds are running from the CI without any issue.
BTW I am using following command in the CI:
npx eas-cli build --platform ios --auto-submit --non-interactive --no-wait

I looked at https://docs.expo.dev/build/building-on-ci/
and it is mentioned in the Prerequisite section "Run a successful build from your local machine"
We want to eliminate this requirement, everything should run from the CI.

did you got this working?

No,  Actually we are now using 'expect' to answer the interactive questions and using Apple API key for Apple authentication. But that requires to pre create app and bundle identifier on apple side. This may be the limitation from apple side where they restrict creating these resources using API key.
